# Detecting foreign IN_MOVED_FROM renames with inotify

Tags: c, linux, inotify

Assume a C program which mirrors the changes in a watched directory to a mirror directory. You recursively watch all subdirectories and use a structure indexed on `watch descriptors` containing the `pathnames` of the watched directories to be able to reconstruct the full pathname of the file in case of an event. This is all you need to process all events but `IN_MOVED_FROM` and `IN_MOVED_TO`. In the case of these two, you, in addition to the aforementioned, seem to also need the following:

- A structure indexed on `cookies` allowing you to store and retrieve the `watch descriptor` and the `filename` of a particular `IN_MOVED_FROM` event once a matching `IN_MOVED_TO` event appears.
- A `timestamp`-ordered queue (redundant) containing cookies which have not yet been paired, so that they can be reinterpreted as `IN_DELETE` events and removed from both of the structures once an arbitrary period of time has passed.
- A `pathname/filename` -> `watch descriptor` relation (redundant), which allows you to effectively find out the `watch descriptor` of a timeouted `cookie` in case the (re)moved filesystem object was a directory, which you now need to unwatch.

Quite some overhead for supporting rename operations. Is there really no other way to detect a foreign rename other than waiting for an unpaired cookie to time out? Given the fact that there [appears to be a way of telling between a local and foreign rename](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-fsdevel/msg46040.html) in [fsnotify](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fsnotify.h), this seems as a rather odd design choice.

Comment: I would consider the mirrordir command.  Either use it directly or peruse the source.  http://linux.die.net/man/1/mirrordir  and http://mirrordir.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.10.49-intl/files.html

Comment: The command doesn't use inotify to detect filesystem events. In fact, it doesn't really seem to be detecting filesystem events at all — it just mirrors the directory and exits instead of monitoring it for changes.

Comment: IMO - that is because a true mirror operates at driver level in the kernel.  rsync also mirrors changes to local/non-local directories. It also runs and exits.  So, other than for learning, I can't see trying to develop a userland mirror.

Comment: This is, indeed, for learning purposes. Also, other than the renames, the inotify library seems a viable userland solution to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `inotify`, you need to set an timeout to handle the mismatched/unpaired/foreign rename operation(eg. `mv` a file into or out of a watched directory), treat them as `IN_CREATE` or `IN_DELETE` events.
Once I worked on a project relating to file synchronization mechanism, faced with the same issue, and solved it the same way.

IMHO, the design of `inotify` API is somewhat disgusting. Take the rename operation as an example, `inotify` interpretes it as **TWO** seperates events. :-(

According to the [link](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-fsdevel/msg46040.html) you give, Linux kernel does distinguish the local/foreign rename operation, and you can achieve this using the `dnotify` interface. But since `dnotify` was already obsoleted by `inotify` interface, I won't recommend this.

reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnotify

Comment: Not only was it deprecated, I couldn't even find any dnotify documentation when I was looking for it.

Comment: @Witiko Take a look at this: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/dnotify.txt

Comment: Lovely. Apparenty, I didn't dig deep enough.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest either studying or just linking to [libinotifytools](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/api/inotifytools_8h.html) library. It handles most if not all of the cases.

Comment: Once I have free hand to choose a library, I most certainly will. For now, I suppose inspecting the source of the library is the most sensible course of action.